# Exception Caught by Image Resource Service (handshake.cc:359)

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart

Flutter cannot load my image and I got an error, and whats wrong with this and how can I solve it? :

```
═══════ Exception caught by image resource service ══════════════════

Handshake error in client (OS Error:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:359))
```

I use IOClient for HttpClient

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

  IOClient get _client => IOClient(HttpClient()
    ..connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 30)
    ..idleTimeout = Duration(seconds: 30)
    ..badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

       CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: item.thumbnail,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  httpHeaders: {
                       'Authorization':
                       'Bearer ${authProvider.token}',
                                },
                      errorWidget: (context, _, __) =>
                              Center(
                               child: Icon(
                                 Icons.broken_image_rounded,
                                   size: 28.0,
                                   color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                         ),
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In main.dart file, add the following class:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) = true;
  }
}
```

And add to main method:

```
HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```